# A sequence converges if and only if every subsequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I want to prove this and intuitively it makes sense. But I'm having a hard time coming up with a proof.
So if a sequence converges, then we have a natural number for which the distance between all terms after it and the limit point get arbitrarily small.
So how can I show that this also holds for every subsequence (which is like a subset of a sequence)?

(are subsequences always infinite?)

Could I suppose that there is a subsequence that doesn't converge to that limit, and find a contradiction?
(and do the same for the other direction?)

Comment: It seems like no effort has been made by the OP to try to answer the question.

Comment: What is the OP?

Comment: OP = original poster; the one who asked the original question. BTW, subsequences are always infinite, yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $x_n \to x$. Then given $\varepsilon> 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. In words, it means that if we go out far enough, $N$ terms, we can talk about the rest of the terms of the sequence as being close enough, within $\varepsilon$, to the limit, $x$.

If you take any subsequence, say $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$, then we can say that the $N^{th}$ term of the subsequence is at least, or beyond, the $N^{th}$ term of the actual sequence. Thus, it shares the same property that the terms of the sequence are within a desired distance from the limit of the main sequence.

Comment: thank you! It's more simple than I thought

Comment: For the other direction, note that the sequence is a subsequene of itself.

Comment: This answer proves one direction. Any hints as to how to prove the other direction?

Comment: A sequence is a subsequence of itself - sort of in the same way that a set us a subset of itself.

Comment: Is it true that if any **increasing** sequence conveges then **any** sequence converges?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $x_n \rightarrow x \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$, $\exists \; N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$.

Now, let $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sub-sequence of $\{x_n\}$. The part I'm writing next will give you intuition as to why the sub-sequence will also thin out to $x$ like the parent sequence.

$\exists \; k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k \geq N$. If not, then $N$ would be an upper bound for the $\textbf{strictly increasing}$ sequence of indices $\{n_1, n_2, \ldots\}$ and the sub-sequence won't have infinite terms. Try to understand this. This is the definition of a subsequence: that the indices are strictly increasing, i.e, $n_1 < n_2 <\ldots$.

Since $n_k \geq N$, we have that $d(x_{n_k}, x) < \epsilon$