# Does this sequence $a_n=(-1)^{n}\cdot \frac{2n^3}{n^3+1}$ converge or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the sequence below converges or diverges.
\begin{align}
a_n=(-1)^{n}\cdot \frac{2n^{3}}{n^{3}+1}, \hspace{0.1cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}
\end{align}
For ease, I found the first 5 terms:

\begin{align}
 a_1&=-1\\ 
 a_2&= \frac{16}{9}\\ 
 a_3&= -\frac{27}{14}\\
 a_4&= \frac{128}{65} \\ 
 a_5&= -\frac{125}{63}
\end{align}

I’m having a hard time understanding why 
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\color{red}{a_n }} \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\color{blue}{a_{n+1}}}
\end{align}
Could someone give me a hint as to why you have $ a_n $ and $ a_{n+1} $?

Comment: It is quite clear that $\frac{2n^3}{n^3+1} \to 2$. This means that this sequence is not converging to 0 and therefore alternating because of $(-1)^n$. The inequality $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}$ does not make sense as both of those limits do not exist.

Comment: Since the sign keeps changing, the limit is either $0$ or does not exist.  Your non-equality is really saying neither expression exists

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1}$ *whenever either limit exists.* So when you write $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1}$, that doesn't make sense. We can only speak of a limit when it actually exists; in this case, it does not.

Comment: I believe you meant to write $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n + 1}$, which does make sense because both of these limits exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subsequences $b_{n_k},c_{n_j}$ which are respectively the even terms of $a_n$ and the odd terms of $a_n$. We have that
$$\lim_{n_k \to \infty}b_{n_k}=\lim_{n_k \to \infty}\frac{2n_k^3}{n_k^3+1}=2$$
$$\lim_{n_j \to \infty}c_{n_j}=\lim_{n_j \to \infty}(-1)\frac{2n_j^3}{n_j^3+1}=-2$$
This [excludes convergence of $a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060064/a-sequence-converges-if-and-only-if-every-subsequence-converges#1060086).

Answer (score 1):

Hint : since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^3}{n^3+1}=2$, then  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2n^3}{n^3+1}$ does not exist. The general case for this as follows:

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n\neq 0$, then  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^n a_n$ does not exist. Can you show why this is the case?

Comment: Because the Limit values alternate between $-L$ and $L$, so $L= Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \neq 0.$ Is that the reason?

Comment: @FernandoSousa, yes, this is the reason. If you found my answer help you please vote for it