# Reason for $|a_n-L| > \frac{1}{i}$, when a sequence is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I have a basic question regarding the limit of a sequence.As per the link given below on the section of convergence of sub sequences, when a sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ diverges, $\forall i>0$, there is a sufficiently large $a_n$ such that $$|a_n-L|>\frac{1}{i}$$.

https://brilliant.org/wiki/subsequences/

I am actually confused with this because when i take $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $L=-1$ and $i=0.01$, i can choose sufficiently large $a_n$ as $1$ and we get $$|1-(-1)|>\frac{1}{0.01}$$ which is false. So am i missing something?

Comment: I believe that $i$ is intended to be an integer, because it's used to construct a subsequence that does not converge.

Comment: So is that definition valid for any integer $i>0$ for a divergent sequence?

Comment: No, take for example $a_n=(-1)^n/100$ then the inequality is true only for $i>50$.

Comment: As for the proof on link, the entire sequence is a subsequence of the sequence i.e we can take $n_k=k$ or if it's excluded (from the definition) we can simply take $n_k=k+1$ it should be pretty easy to prove that choice implies convergence of the original sequence.

Comment: i think it makes sense if we say, $\exists i_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-L|>\frac{1}{i}$, $\forall i \geq i_0$

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

> Suppose ... that $\{a_n\}$ does not converge (to $x$). Then, for every $i>0$, there is an arbitrarily large $a_n$ such that $|a_n-x|>\frac1i$.​

is true, with minor clarifications.  But as we'll see, it's not so critical to the proof of the desired claim.

**Claim.** Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence, and $x$ is a real number such that $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $x$.  Then there exists a positive integer $i_0$ such that for all positive integers $n$ and integers $i > i_0$, there exists an integer $n_i$ such that $n_i > n$ and $$|a_{n_i} - x | > \frac{1}{i}$$

Before the proof, remember the definition of convergence and the proper way to negate quantified statements.  We say that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $x$ if *for every* $\epsilon > 0$ *there exists* $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that *for all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - x | < \epsilon$.

The negation of this is: $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $x$ if *there exists* $\epsilon > 0$ such that *for all* $N \in \mathbb{N}$ *there exists* $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ and $|a_n - x| \geq \epsilon$.

*Proof of claim.* Since $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $x$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ as in the previous paragraph.  Choose $i_0$ to be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{i_0} < \epsilon$.  Suppose that $i$ is a positive integer greater than $i_0$, and $n$ is any positive integer.  Since $a_n \not\to x$, there exists an integer $n_i > n$ such that $$|a_n - x | \geq \epsilon > \frac{1}{i_0} > \frac{1}{i}$$ QED.

But this is too clever by half.  In order to reach a contradiction, it's sufficient to find an $\epsilon > 0$ and an increasing sequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $|a_{n_k} - x| \geq \epsilon$ for all $k$. This is guaranteed if $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $x$. Then $\{a_{n_k}\}$ cannot converge to $x$ either.

But even *this* is unnecessary.  Suppose every subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converges to $x$.  The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$, so it converges to $x$ as well.

See also [A sequence converges if and only if every subsequence converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1060064/2785) from this site.

Comment: I am confused with $n_i$ and $n$, Is $n_i$ dependent on $i$?

Comment: Is it wrong if i say that when the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is divergent, then $\exists$ $i_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that we can find $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n_0}-L|>\frac{1}{i}$, $\forall i\geq i_0$.

Comment: @Umeshshankar: (1) I think that was a typo. $n_i$ does “depend on” $i$ it follows $i$ in quantification.  (2) That's correct.  But again, probably not useful or necessary.

Comment: Why it is not useful?. I have proved the following way. Since the subsequence $\left\{a_{n_k}\right\}$ is convergent to $L$, we have $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N_p \in \left\{n_k\right\}$ such that $|a_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon$, when ever $n_k \geq N_p$.  Now choose $N_p=n_0$ and $\epsilon =\frac{1}{i_o}$, then we have $|a_{n_0}-L|<\frac{1}{i_0}$ which contradicts $|a_{n_0}-L|>\frac{1}{i_0}$. Hence the proof.

Comment: I don't see in this argument where you used $|a_{n_0} - L| > \frac{1}{i}$ for all $i \geq i_0$.  That's why I said it was unnecessary.

Comment: I used it because i assumed that $a_n$ diverges. Finally if you see the comment above i arrived at a contradiction.